# Tagging C++ questions with C++ compilers

Tags: discussion, retag-request

For two of the major C++ compilers, we have two tag options each:

[gcc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gcc): the GNU Compiler Collection. It's the de facto standard C compiler on Linux and supports many other languages and platforms as well.
[g++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/g%2b%2b): the C++ frontend to the GNU Compiler Collection (gcc).

and

[clang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clang): the LLVM compiler front end for C/C++/Objective-C, which provides fast compiles, useful error and warning messages, an accommodating license and offers an extensible platform for building sou…
[clang++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clang%2b%2b): a C, C++, and Objective-C compiler which encompasses preprocessing, parsing, optimization, code generation, assembly, and linking. Depending on which high-level mode setting is pass…

A lot of C++ questions are tagged [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) [gcc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gcc) (7k questions) or [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)[clang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clang) (1.8k), where those are really broad family tags. Should they be retagged to [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)[g++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/g%2b%2b) (4k questions currently) and [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)[clang++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clang%2b%2b) (388)?

Comment: Maybe [g++] and [clang++] should be synonymized to [gcc] and [clang] instead, respectively?

Comment: @Deduplicator Seems reasonable to me

Comment: Based on your description though, doesn't [clang] also compile C++?

Answer (score 2):

First, it seems to me that the difference between [gcc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gcc) and [g++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/g%2b%2b) are not the same as the difference between [clang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clang) and [clang++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clang%2b%2b).

[gcc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gcc) refers to the entirety of the compiler collection, all languages for which the GCC stack works. [g++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/g%2b%2b) refers specifically to the part of GCC that compiles C++.

With Clang, it's kinda the opposite. [clang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clang), according to the tag info, refers to ''just'' the compiler front-end. But it does so for all of the languages that Clang project has front-end support for: C, C++, and Objective variants thereof. [clang++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clang%2b%2b) doesn't refer to just the C++ version of the front end (again, according to the tag info). It instead refers to the entire compilation suite, from text file to output binaries.

[clang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clang) stops with LLVM code; [clang++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clang%2b%2b) continues through to linking and so forth.

So it seems that the combination of [clang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clang) and [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) is meaningful: it's for questions about the Clang front-end, when used to compile C++ code, or when you're actually modifying the Clang front-end, like if you're making static analysis tools or something.

Similarly, the combination of [clang++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clang%2b%2b) and [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) is meaningful, because the tag description for [clang++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clang%2b%2b) is not ''solely'' about C++. So there's nothing to be changed with regard to languages; you need to use a language tag with both [clang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clang) and [clang++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clang%2b%2b).

Personally, I'd prefer that the [clang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clang) tag refers to Clang-as-a-build-suite, while a tag like `clang-fe` could be used for issues related solely to Clang-as-a-front-end. [clang++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clang%2b%2b) referring to the full source-to-executable stack is something of a misnomer, considering how few people use it as such.

As for [gcc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gcc) vs. [g++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/g%2b%2b)... how much do we *really* care about that distinction? I'd be fine if [g++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/g%2b%2b) vanished into the aether and we just used [gcc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gcc) + appropriate language tags. It seems obvious to me that if you tag your code [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c)/[gcc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gcc), you're not talking about the C++ parts of the compiler. Similarly, if you tag you question [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java)/[gcc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gcc), you're not interested in the C part of the compiler.

I just see no need for a tag for a multi-language compiler that incorporates the compiler and the language in one tag. You're still going to put the language tag in there, right?

Comment: Synonymize then?